How to only install Boost 64bit from a single Chocolatey package?
Currently, I am installing Boost using Chocolatey,
choco install -y boost-msvc-14.2 --version 1.74.0

This installs both the 32 and 64-bit version of the library.
I believe I don't need the 32-bit version, and to save space and time (each version is ˜150MB, and the files are downloaded separately); I would like to download only one of the two versions.
$ choco install -y boost-msvc-14.2 --version 1.74.0
Chocolatey v2.3.0
Installing the following packages:
boost-msvc-14.2
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Downloading package from source 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
Progress: Downloading boost-msvc-14.2 1.74.0... 100%
boost-msvc-14.2 v1.74.0 [Approved]
boost-msvc-14.2 package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Downloading boost-msvc-14.2 
  from 'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost-binaries/1.74.0/boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-32.exe'
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\gitlab_runner\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\boost-msvc-14.2\1.74.0\boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-32.exe (150.86 MB).
Download of boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-32.exe (150.86 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Installing boost-msvc-14.2...
boost-msvc-14.2 has been installed.
Downloading boost-msvc-14.2 64 bit
  from 'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost-binaries/1.74.0/boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe'
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\gitlab_runner\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\boost-msvc-14.2\1.74.0\boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe (162.56 MB).
Download of boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe (162.56 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Installing boost-msvc-14.2
...

How can I download (or at least install) only one of the architectures (64bit)?
Is there a command line for choco to install only one of the two versions?
(other scripted ways in Windows to install Boost are welcome)
This list he Choco page https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/boost-msvc-14.2

Looking at the package you have specified (boost-msvc-14.2), it intentionally installs both x86 and x64 versions of the libraries:

This package includes Boost headers and libs compiled with Visual Studio 2019 for 32bit and 64bit Windows.

There is no way to control this beyond modifying the package, or talking to the package maintainer to add package parameters (or handling for the x86/x64 arguments) to influence it.

Makes sense, I am trying to download and install the package manually, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78632039/how-to-download-and-run-installer-with-powershell?noredirect=1#comment138633631_78632039

I ended up doing this manually, https://stackoverflow.com/a/78634605/225186

Thank you for the other answers.
Chocolatey is great but for installing Boost it is an overkill.
I ended up doing this:
$ Invoke-WebRequest -UserAgent curl https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost-binaries/1.74.0/boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe -OutFile boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe
$ .\boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe /sp- /verysilent /suppressmsgboxes /norestart | more

which takes half the time of choco and works too.
The process runs in 20 minutes instead of 40 minutes in a CI machine.

Yow, that's a lengthy install! I'll note that Chocolatey was only taking twice the time because it was downloading and running the installer twice! I'm thinking about PRing the package to respect the parameters, as it does seem better that way - unsure if it'll be accepted, though.

@JamesRuskin, yes, it downloaded the package twice (32 and 64-bit) and installed both versions, but in the end, the job used only the 64-bit version. It is not a defect of Chocolatey but the Boost package. Admittedly, these are very slow (low priority) CI machines: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/jobs/7137617284#L124. It would be even cooler if I could install only the subset of Boost libraries that I needed. In any case, it seems faster than installing/compiling with Vcpkg.

With Choco whenever you are installing something you can but don't have to specify the bit version. People usually don't say this feature a lot but you can its pretty easy just at the end of the install like the choco install package name --bitversion and it can be used both to install the 38-bit version and the 64-bit version. In your scenario for you to use this command you will need to run choco install -y boost-msvc-14.2 --version 1.74.0 --x64or if you lets say wanted to install the 38-bit version you don't run x38 but instead the x86 so it will be choco install -y boost-msvc-14.2 --version 1.74.0 --x86

Now I found a complete lits of choco command line options, https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/install/#options-and-switches. --x86 is mentioned but not --x64. I am going to try.

So did it work or not

No, I tried with choco install -y boost-msvc-14.2 --version 1.74.0 --x64 and it produces the same output: see here: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/jobs/7111223247#L112
